# Error de Android Studio con mi pc AMD

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Tengo un problema, y es que estoy iniciando en Android Studio y tal parece que el Gradle falla porque no puede cargar una librería. En resumen, el error que me aparece es que el transcribo a continuación:

> Gradle sync failed: Can't load library:
>   C:\Users\equipo.gradle\native\19\windows-amd64\native-platform.dll

¿Alguien me puede ayudar? Desde ya muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Algún problema tiene el .dll para desarrollo nativo con nuevas versiones de `Android Studio`, o posiblemente no se encuentra el archivo `native-platform.dll`, se deben de tener estos dos archivos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Elimina el folder `\native` y reinicia `Android Studio` para que se vuelva a crear su contenido.

```
C:\Users\equipo.gradle\native\
```

asegura que el archivo `native-platform.dll` se encuentre dentro.

Comment: cuando hablas de reiniciar android... ¿a que te refieres?. Discúlpame la pregunta, es que no quiero cometer equivocaciones.

Comment: Reiniciar, puedes cerrar Android Studio, borrar el folder e iniciar nuevamente Android Studio.

Comment: Ya borre la carpeta \native del directorio del windows, y cerré Android Studio, sin embargo no paso nada, sigue de la misma manera.